# How to change custom string format to Datetime format in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have textbox asssociated with model class having value like

> "03/28/2014".

I want to convert this to DateTime with `28/03/2014` format. I have tried following ways, but I'm not getting anywhere close...

```
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
string date = timesheetModel.START_DATE;
string pattern = "dd-mm-yyyy"; 

DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(date,pattern,theCultureInfo).
DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime(timesheetModel.START_DATE);
```

and also `DateTime.Parse(date);`
By this getting compile time error:

```
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

I have tried also in modal class with Types like:

```
public string date{get;set;} // by this type not converting to datetime

public DateTime date{get;set;} // not able to access values to controller
```

Is there any other solution for this? Because the textbox value format is fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't your pattern be: "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Comment: I tried that pattern but getting same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should Use DateTime.ParseExact with the format "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("03/28/2014", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

you can go though the below link for more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: Sorry. Getting Error like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I have tried this attempt also.

Comment: I have just updated code and I have tested like this and its working fine @Sanjay

Comment: Ya, getting like this, but if i call from model class with textbox value  raising Exception.